# Is there an equivalent to Game Center for Windows 8 Store applications?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, leaderboard

I've found ScoreLoop for WP7 but can't find anything for Windows 8 games.  Ideally I want something that manages leaderboards, awards, badges, etc.

Does such a thing exist for Windows 8 Store apps?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not are where to obtain the bits etc, but this was talked about at build 2011:
http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/PLAT-756T

Comment: It's a managed program - more info at [http://www.xbox.com/developers](http://www.xbox.com/developers)

Comment: XBox does provide all this but to have access to it you need meet a stack of criteria that an Indie developer won't meet (number of employees, revenue forecasts, have a game published already, etc). Something like ScoreLoop would be ideal, but they don't have a W8 client